# Asp.net..Printing

Tags: asp.net

I have a button in asp.net (c#) that I want after click this button I could print from my html table that is in a update panel ,I only  want Print my html table not all page
is there any component?
thanx very much

Answer (score 3):

2 ways to handle it:

- CSS to define a print media
- Reporting services, hit the data directly from a sproc / direct table
  and print a table layout of the data.

## Based on OP comment

Straight from W3c:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Read specifically about print media, it means you can define a .css file in your asp.net project with the media type "print":

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

This is nice because you can now define CSS to hide all elements on your screen:

`display:none`

Except the div / table of your choice:

```
#myDiv {
 display: block;
}
```

In your asp.net page you have this define:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" title="Printer-Friendly Style" 
         type="text/css" href="printStyle.css">
```

This tells your application to use the `printStyle.css` file when it comes to printing your page.
And once you do try to print the app will use printStyle and all the formatting and styles you have defined.

Here is a good example: https://web.archive.org/web/20200724145536/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/demos/printMediaCss.html

For the second point, if you are running SQL Server, reporting services is free.  Of course you will need to set this up and deploy reports.  Its a bit out of the scope of this question.  If you do have reporting services you may want to open a new topic and ask questions about it.
Otherwise just create a print style css file.

Comment: please explain more if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the CSS @print Media Type to hide the stuff you don't want to print.

Check out [the w3 Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) for a basic overview.

Comment: Is it me or does anyone else despise w3schools ?

Comment: I don't use them for anything more than a basic overview, outside of that; there's tons of better tutorial sites out there.

Don't get me started on CodeProject though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes to define media type like @print, @screen and then mark appropriate parts of your webapge with those classes.

For the button to do the print, you will need to add: `onClientClick="window.print()"` to the button's definition.

Use CSS like this:

```
@media print
{
  printOnly {display:block;}
  screenOnly {display:none;}
}

@media screen
{
  printOnly {display:none;}
  screenOnly {display:block;}
}
```

Then simply decorate your DIVs or other elements with the classes:

`<div class="screenOnly">this will not print but will show on screen</div>` or

`<div class="printOnly">this will not show on screen but will print</div>`

Comment: can i want you explain more about first part of your answer?this part is related to this part of my question that I only want print my table not all my page?can you explain more?