# Opening a print dialog box in another tab on a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a `datalist` inside a div. I want to print it.
The code has been done for printing on a button click but opens the print dialog form in the same tab itself..
what I want is to open the print dialog box in another tab so that if I don't want to print it i can simply close the tab and start working normally with my form...

I am using the following code at design time.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnprintlabel" OnClientClick="printdiv('div_print');"  
            Text="PrintLabel" Width="132px" onclick="btnprintlabel_Click" 
            Font-Bold="True" Visible="False" runat="server" />
```

Comment: can you put your `printdiv` function in your code?

Comment: use a tag for print using javascript and add your button click event in those function.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use same views, but have 2 CSS files (one with `media="screen"` and the other with `media"print"`).

### Detail

The `media"print"` applies only when you give print command to your page.

You can hide other controls in this css and print your page.

You can go through the following links

1. [Asp.net..Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002105/asp-net-printing)
2. http://haacked.com/archive/2006/03/13/CSSBasedPrintingTip.aspx

### Edit 1

If you don't want to use above simple go through this link
[Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)